# Google Analytics - server-side timing hit (Measurement Protocol)

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, measurement-protocol, pageviews

I created a library to use Google Analytics (Universal Analytics) on the server-side with asp.net core. It automatically creates `pageview`, `event` and `timing` hits for each request and sends them to Google Analytics via the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters).

### Problem

*How to imitate the timing hits that analytics.js sends automatically?*

There is no documentation on how to send timing data that shows up under **Site Speed** / **Page Timings** in Google Analytics (page load time, server response time etc.). I also coulnd't reverse engineer how analytics.js sends this data.

### What I tried

I tried using the related parameters (page load time and server response time) to (1) send a timing hit and to (2) add timing parameters to the pageview hit, but Google Analytics doesn't show any timing values - even after 24 hours. My current workaround is to use the user timing parameters that show up under **User Timings** and use the user timing label to specify the url. However, the reporting features for user timings are rather limited compared to **Page Timings** reporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting up a test website with the default `analytics.js` script and setting the timing sample rate to 100% I could finally log a normal page timing hit (not user timing). It has all parameters of a `pageview` hit plus the actual `timing` parameters.

**Required Parameters**

- `tid=UA-123456789-1`
- `t=timing`
- `dl=https://example.com/a`
- `dt=Some%20Title`
- `plt=1513`
- `pdt=3`
- `dns=30`
- `rrt=4`
- `srt=138`
- `tcp=451`
- `dit=1261`
- `clt=126`

**Warning**: *Adding user timing parameters (`utc`, `utv`, `utt`) or omitting some of the timing parameters may cause Google Analytics to ignore the page timing hit and not show any values under 'Site Speed' and 'Page Timing'.*

Answer (score 0):

The values ​​in those reports requires a certain amount of hits collected by Analytics, this may be why you don't see the data.

Following you can find some documentation on `timing` hit type the type with an example of a call to use with the Measurement Protocol.

**Server Response Time**
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#srt

**Page Load Time**
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#plt

Here you can find an example of timing hit to send via MP:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#usertiming

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/?v=1&tid=UA-XXXXX-Y&cid=555&t=timing&utc=jsonLoader&utv=load&utt=5000&utl=jQuery&dns=100&pdt=20&rrt=32&tcp=56&srt=12

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I already put the link to the parameter documentation in my question. The linked documentation doesn't tell how timing values (user timing and page timing) can be sent for a specific page/url.

Comment: The hit builder is not really helpful: It's more like a formal validation, but it doesn't check whether the combination of parameters makes any sense.

Comment: You can try to setup that hit in a website with 100% of frequency and check values sent to Analytics to understand what combinations make sense.